# Save live video stream on orientation change

Tags: android, mvvm, screen-orientation, live-streaming

I'm trying to make an app that displays a live streaming video (currently from twitch), nothing else.

I have encountered a problem with orientation changes. Whenever an orientation change happens it reloads the stream. With usual video I would save time and just keep it playing from that point but with live streamed video it wouldn't work. I have also tried using `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in manifest but I got pointed out that it's not a good practice to use it.

I'm also doing this project in MVVM so any stored data is most likely in the `ViewModel`.

Here's my code:

### **VideoActivity**

```
class VideoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var videoViewModel: VideoViewModel
    lateinit var videoView : VideoView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video)
        videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView)

        videoViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(VideoViewModel::class.java)
        videoViewModel.videoData.observe(this, Observer {
            val video = Uri.parse(it)
            videoView.setVideoURI(video)
            videoView.requestFocus()
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener {
                videoView.start()
            }
        })

    }
}
```

### VideoViewModel

```
class VideoViewModel (application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val videoData : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        val videoURL =
            "https://video-weaver.fra02.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/CtIDniDZISZg6pdwWWtn7F96H-gSYWvF3ry6fGuRtSEKjCX6-K5R7ggMJhI7cDgngS6SeqgYVWIJKC-qEyy94XusXug8TT1s6mfDq1bQ2id7XeHKZgYS0fucGPPV-pDBCXFkDxLUclYsSon7jxM-t5ydBqOn5N1SOh2Jf1DBr4NmxAxUCtcNVg4UOvfLQrjtQM_AiATNibsFMyiQZRaRGQU96jNvAUJkLBUqPEAwOBbmJJZQbXp3AJIGIm8RiyJ0uufWiTYdQBu44Ri_jihP6QAtXLHjvwqcyMnWJDtL46fwb-QPkWiLm2XEJJfG6x1EUZ8V8Qk1s9A19PTHEp_c18_mc7TIoY-0P7qI7uurA4mQ1kqflkBXKujsMh_kdDfBCoU7UImYrORGe1BSTC8QHStiSSDdLoYwWoKcQGBSLNZXp4L6YtJHBMjXiykgiVZFS2NgoYCgl6rqEzCqb0QXTjNts3B0DmKh4J3V2l2keZh8xW-uymoUCXi7X9E-xOolHpTg_K79dhWitewwKJy0z8NxVMkbBrGeAo75Fl9-fmoIVDQqAGANywH4NQEbmtFH8sh4FnRdBfhWRM9FLYrre3CjGB-LaBAihRFe82vGJ7F8cvN62RIQZGIKfcl18Z53bjDPmV_vzhoMf2b95YbSnSvpzZHW.m3u8"
        videoData.postValue(videoURL)

    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that you will need to stop using `VideoView` and switch to `MediaPlayer`, so you can retain the `MediaPlayer` itself across configuration changes, attaching it to a new `SurfaceView` in the new activity instance.

Comment: @CommonsWare I didn't manage to find a convenient way of using `MediaPlayer` with m3u8. Besides that, I can't make it work with `ViewModel` as all callbacks are very intertwined with the `SurfaceView`. I'm still new to MVVM so it is a bit difficult for me to understand everything at the same time

Comment: "I didn't manage to find a convenient way of using MediaPlayer with m3u8" -- well, `VideoView` uses `MediaPlayer`. It just "owns" that `MediaPlayer`, so you cannot readily hold onto it across the configuration change, let alone reuse it. "I'm still new to MVVM so it is a bit difficult for me to understand everything at the same time" -- then perhaps don't worry about reloading the stream. Or, go back to your `android:configChanges` solution.